# Stop listening to a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm doing

```
IBusControl.Stop()
```

to let my consumer stop listening, but it keeps going. When in the debugger I'm still getting in the Consumer method where the published methods are read. Am I missing something? Or how can I disconnect from the bus or the queue?

Comment: `Stop` is the correct approach, but any in-flight messages will complete before the bus shuts down completely. Each receive endpoint is shut down separately, but at the same time. Do you have a log of the stop being called and consumers still being invoked?

Comment: After a couple of days, it started working like I expected... hmm problem solved